# Template Functions and Const/NonConst Reference Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, function, parameters, reference

New to C++ and learning from books so I can be quite pedantic or miopic in my reasoning.

In the case of template functions, I have read that when a parameter is passed by Reference, only conversions from Reference / Pointer to NonConst to Reference / Pointer to Const are alllowed.

That means I believe that

```
template <typename T> int compare(T&, T&);
```

should fail when calling compare(ci1, ci1), with ci1 being consntant int, as conversions from Const to NonCost are not allowed for Reference parameters.

However it works in my compiler (Visual C++ 10). Can someone explain me what I get wrong?

---

```
template <typename T> int compare(T&, T&);  

template <typename T> int compare(T &v1,  T &v2)
{
    // as before
    cout << "compare(T, T)" << endl;
    if (v1 < v2) return -1;
    if (v2 < v1) return 1;
    return 0;
}


const int ci1 = 10;
const int ci2 = 20;

int i1 = 10;
int i2 = 20;

compare(ci1, ci1);     
compare(i1, i1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call

```
compare( ci1, ci1 );
```

yields T as type `const int` (in your preferred notation).

The effective function signature is then

```
int compare( int const&, int const& )
```

You can use `typeid(x).name()` the check out what types you actually have.

Note: with g++ that yields some ungrokkable short forms, which you then need to use a special g++-specific runtime lib function to decode.

Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 2):

`T` will be whatever type the variable is - in your case `const int`, so the final instantiation of `compare` will look like

```
// T = const int
int compare(const int& v1, const int& v2)
```

in your first case with `compare(ci1,ci2)` and like

```
// T = int
int compare(int& v1, int& v2)
```

with `compare(i1,i2)`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the template is instantiated with `T = const int`, which is fine.

You will get an error if you try `compare(i1, ci1)`, since that will fail to find a template argument compatible with both `int &` and `const int &`. Changing the signature to `compare(const T &, const T &)` will fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of compare(ci1, ci1); T will be const int. This is why it works

Answer (score 1):

This is acceptable because the function can be instantiated when you substitute `int const` for `T`.